# Why do we have $V^{1/2} \otimes V^{1/2} = V^0 \oplus V^1$ (spin).

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, lie-algebras

I would like to understand why we have :

$V^{1/2} \otimes V^{1/2} = V^0 \oplus V^1$

I need to find a proof of this, and in fact I am looking for the proof of the general case where we have :

$$ V^{j} \otimes V^{k}= \sum_{i=|j-k|}^{j+k} \oplus V^i$$

If possible a proof with the less mathematical tools needed (I am doing physics, I know linear algebra, some basics of group & representation theory but this is not my domain of expertise).

In my notations : $V^{j}$ is a complex vector space of dimension $2*j+1$ (it is the space where the spin $j$ lives)

Comment: It looks like the result you want to prove is the one sometimes called Clebsch-Gordan formula. IMHO it is best viewed as a result describing the irreducible submodules of a tensor product of two irreducible representations of $SU(2)$, $SL_2(\Bbb{C})$ or $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\Bbb{C})$. Somehow I get the feeling that you may not appreciate a few hours of representation theory of Lie algebras as an answer :-)

Comment: Anyway, this special case can probably be handled without much machinery. But, you need to share your description of the spaces $V^{1/2}$, $V^0$ and $V^{1}$ as well as how the spin shows here. Otherwise we would be guessing your notation, and the answer may not be useful to you. Like: what do you call the basis vectors? How are your ladder operators defined? Do you know how they and other matrices act on the vectors of those spaces? Do not assume that everybody would use the same notation your textbook is using!

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Well in fact it is indeed linked with Clebsch-Gordan coefficents. I think that $V^j$ is just a vector space of dimension $2*j+1$ but I don't know if there is more to say about it. Yes my question is  probably not rigorously defined but it is part of my misunderstanding :) I just know it is the space where the spin j lives so for me it is just a complex vector space of dimension 2*j+1 but I probably forget an assumption on it !

Answer (score 3):

Without loss of generality, assume that $j\geq k$.  The dimension of the weight space of the $\mathfrak{su}(2)$-module $M:=V^j\otimes V^k$ with weight $j+k-t$ is precisely $t+1$, where $t\leq 2k$ is a nonnegative integer.  Since each weight space of the simple $\mathfrak{su}(2)$-module $V^r$ is $1$ for each half integer $r\geq 0$, we conclude that the multiplicity of $V^{j+k}$ in $M$ is $1$, and so the weight space of $M/V^{j+k}$ with weight $j+k-1$ is of dimension $1$ (provided that $k>0$).  Thus, the multiplicity of $V^{j+k-1}$ in $M$ is $1$ in case $k>0$.  Then, you proceed by induction and show that the multiplicity of $V^r$ in $M$ is $1$ for each $r=j+k,j+k-1,j+k-2,\ldots,j-k$.  That is,
$$M=V^j\otimes V^k=\bigoplus_{r=j-k}^{j+k}\,V^r\,.$$
For this result, you need to know [Weyl's Complete Reducibility Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_theorem_on_complete_reducibility).  In particular,
$$V^{1/2}\otimes V^{1/2}=V^0\oplus V^1\,.$$
However, to get a generator of the submodule isomorphic to $V^r$ in $M$, it is not very easy (well, not too difficult, but cumbersome in my opinion).

Let $\mathfrak{su}(2)_\mathbb{C}=\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})=\mathbb{C}x\oplus\mathbb{C}h\oplus\mathbb{C}y$, where $x$ is the creation operator, $y$ the annihilation operator, and $h=[x,y]$.  In the special case $j=k=\frac{1}{2}$, we observe that $$V^{1/2}=\mathbb{C}u^+\oplus \mathbb{C}u^-\,$$ where $u^+$ is a highest-weight vector of $V^{1/2}$ and $u^-=y\cdot u^+$ a lowest-weight vector.  Clearly, $V^1$ is generated by $u^+\otimes u^+$.  That is,
$$V^1=\mathbb{C}\left(u^+\otimes u^+\right) \oplus \mathbb{C}\left(u^+\otimes u^-+u^-\otimes u^+\right) \oplus \mathbb{C}\left(u^-\otimes u^-\right)\,.$$On the other hand, $V^0$ is $1$-dimensional, so you need a linear combination
$$a\left(u^+\otimes u^-\right)+ b\left(u^-\otimes u^+\right)$$ 
that vanishes when $x$ and $y$ are applied.  It can be easily seen that $a+b=0$ is required, so
$$V^0=\mathbb{C}\left(u^+\otimes u^--u^-\otimes u^+\right)\,.$$